# LDO transient performance enhancement circuit understanding

Tags: mosfet, analog, cmos, ldo, transient

For the following LDO circuit, how does the transient performance enhancement circuit sub-block in green color works ?

[image]

Comment: You have asked 50 questions and only 6 you have formally selected an answer to. This is disappointing given that this is a free service and closing questions down (when good answers are given) is both a mark of respect and an indication to other users that a particular answer can be relied upon due to formal acceptance. If there are good reasons not to accept then why not pursue answerers to make better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit controls the resistance in series with that cap.

How?

In lower right, you'll see 1:1:4

The fet over the leftmost "1" sends current up, to a diode_connected fet, and to gate of the fet used as resistor.

Chances are the fet_as_resistor is a long_channel fet, with Length much greater than Width.

Comment: I tried to [replicate](https://gist.github.com/promach/0aa27091e5f6617460d14a0789e6cca0) the above [LDO circuit](https://i.imgur.com/ium7yH0.png) in LTSpice, but [it does not work yet ....](https://i.imgur.com/p6Ae47X.png)

Comment: How does it control the resistance ?